# Downloading earliest 3200 tweets with Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've been trying to download the entire timelines of a number of users on Twitter. While I'm able to download the most recent 3,200 tweets from a user, I was wondering if anyone had any success downloading timelines in opposite chronological order--i.e. from first tweet to the 3,200th?

The best I can do is view these tweets in my browser via Twitter's Advanced Search feature. But there's not even a way to copy-paste these tweets into a csv where I can analyze them.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get tweets older than the most recent 3,200.

This is a limitation of [Twitter's underlying `GET statuses/user_timeline` API endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) in the REST API:

> This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user’s most recent Tweets. Native retweets of other statuses by the user is included in this total, regardless of whether `include_rts` is set to `false` when requesting this resource.

Comment: I was afraid of that. It looks like even if I use the web-interface for their Advanced Search function, I can't even parse it out of the html with beautifulsoup :-(

Answer (score 2):

I submitted a bot [TwEater](https://github.com/mutux/TwEater) on GitHub today, aiming at collecting earlier data more than 3200 for text mining tasks. Hopefully it might help you.

Comment: Cool, I'll check this out!